# Getting data in the correct recharts format for a monthly bar chart view

Tags: javascript, recharts

I have some data which looks like so:

```
data = [
{'id': 1, 'fields': {'name': 'name-1', 'team': 'team-1', 'date': '2022-04-01'}},
{'id': 2, 'fields': {'name': 'name-2', 'team': 'team-2', 'date': '2022-04-02'}},
{'id': 3, 'fields': {'name': 'name-3', 'team': 'team-3', 'date': '2022-04-03'}},
{'id': 4, 'fields': {'name': 'name-4', 'team': 'team-1', 'date': '2022-04-02'}},
{'id': 5, 'fields': {'name': 'name-5', 'team': 'team-2', 'date': '2022-04-02'}},

]
```

What I am trying to do is get it in the format so I can visualize it with recharts. What I am going for is something like this:
[Monthly chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs8ff.png)

I have been able to get the data into a format where I have counted all the unique teams by doing:

```
  const counts = {};
  data.forEach(function (x) {counts[x.fields['team']] = (counts[x.fields['team']] || 0) + 1;});
```

which gives me the format of:

```
{'team-1': 2, 'team-2': 2, 'team-3': 1}
```

and I have been able to get all the items in a given month by doing:

```
const monthCountArr = new Array(12).fill(0);
data.forEach(({ fields }) => monthCountArr[new Date(fields['date']).getMonth()] += 1);
```

which yields:

```
[{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0: 3: 5, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0}]
```

but, now I am not so sure how to approach the rest of this problem so I can get the chart to show how many people are in each team for a given month.

I am not even sure what kind of a format I need? maybe something like this:

```
data = [
{'month': 'Apr', 'teams': {'team-1': 2, 'team-2': 2, 'team-3': 1}}

]
```

then I could plot three different bars (one for each team) and their respective values all under the month of April which would be on the X-axis.

I don't know, I've been going at this for hours and I just cannot figure out how to proceed.

The recharts documentation has an example where there data is like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Page A',
    uv: 4000,
    pv: 2400,
    amt: 2400,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page B',
    uv: 3000,
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page C',
    uv: 2000,
    pv: 9800,
    amt: 2290,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page D',
    uv: 2780,
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page E',
    uv: 1890,
    pv: 4800,
    amt: 2181,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page F',
    uv: 2390,
    pv: 3800,
    amt: 2500,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page G',
    uv: 3490,
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100,
  },
];
```

so maybe I need my data in this format:

```
data = [
{'month': 'April', 
'team-1': 2,
'team-2': 2,
'team-3': 1}
]
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that way. Hope you are referring to this example only https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleBarChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go around and transform data as follows;

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from "recharts";

const rawData = [
  { id: 1, fields: { name: "name-1", team: "team-1", date: "2022-04-01" } },
  { id: 2, fields: { name: "name-2", team: "team-2", date: "2022-04-02" } },
  { id: 3, fields: { name: "name-3", team: "team-3", date: "2022-04-03" } },
  { id: 4, fields: { name: "name-4", team: "team-1", date: "2022-04-02" } },
  { id: 5, fields: { name: "name-5", team: "team-2", date: "2022-04-02" } }
];


// get unique list of teams in order to tell recharts to understand as a bar
const teams = Array.from(new Set(rawData.map((i) => i.fields.team)));

/*
Shape the data in the following form;
{
  date: '2022-12-22', <- this will be taken as the X axis
  'team-1': 1, <- each team data will be taken as the bar height
  'team-2': 2
}

*/
const data = Object.values(
  rawData.reduce((acc, d) => {
    const {
      fields: { date, team }
    } = d;
    acc[date] = acc[date] || { date };
    acc[date][team] = (acc[date][team] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BarChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="date" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      {teams.map((t) => (
        <Bar dataKey={t} />
      ))}
    </BarChart>
  );
}
```

It will produce follwing result;
[simple bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bU3G.png)

Comment: Exactly what I have been trying to do, thank you so much!